# Creating new workbooks after filtering data

Tags: vba, loops, filter, filtering

I am trying to modify a script found in this page: https://www.listendata.com/2015/04/excel-vba-filtering-and-copy-pasting-to.html which in synthesis would allow me to filter each unique value in a column, copy the data, create a new workbook and then paste said data in a Loop.

The issue is that everytime the script goes on to create the new workbook and paste the copied data, I receive the error **Run-time Error 9: Subscript out of range** precisely in the line boldened below:

```
Sub test()
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
' -------------------
  
Dim x As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim last As Long
Dim sht As String
Dim newBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim Workbk As Excel.Workbook

'Specify sheet name in which the data is stored
sht = "Report"

'Workbook where VBA code resides
Set Workbk = ThisWorkbook

'New Workbook
Set newBook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
Workbk.Activate

'change filter column in the following code
last = Workbk.Sheets(sht).Cells(Rows.Count, "BR").End(xlUp).Row

With Workbk.Sheets(sht)
Set rng = .Range("A1:BR" & last)
End With

Workbk.Sheets(sht).Range("G1:G" & last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("BT1"), Unique:=True
For Each x In Workbk.Sheets(sht).Range([BT2], Cells(Rows.Count, "BT").End(xlUp))

With rng
.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=x.Value
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

*newBook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value*
newBook.Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
End With
Next x

' Turn off filter
Workbk.Sheets(sht).AutoFilterMode = False

With Application
.CutCopyMode = False
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

' -------------------
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Check."
    
End Sub
```

It would be worth to mention that the new workbook is created. However it gets stuck here and I cannot see the reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting bitten by an implicit `ActiveWorkbook`.

```
newBook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
```

Qualify the `Sheets` with the workbook in question:

```
newBook.Sheets.Add(After:=newBook.Sheets(newBook.Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
```